# Is there a way to annotate a related field in django?

Tags: django

Is something like this possible?

```
m = Message.objects.annotate(room__something=Value('DOH', output_field=CharField())).select_related('room')

m.room.something == 'DOH' # is true
```

Logged an enhancement request -

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/33242#ticket

Comment: What _use_ would you have of such a feature though?... And if you want to ask for that to be added into Django why ask it here?

Comment: Because if somebody wonders the same they can follow the link to see whether there is any point logging it themselves.  Don't know why you are questioning the point of the feature, unless IT IS possible.  I get the feeling it isn't though.

Comment: You can use [Prefetch objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects) with `prefetch_related` and specify the queryset for the related model there (and hence annotate it). I question the feature because it doesn't seem useful, what extra data you want to annotate it is _extra_ data why does it need to be annotated on the related model?

Comment: I'll take a look at the prefetch_related, thanks.  I'm using django graphene at the moment where it is common to have extra fields on the graphql object which is representing a django model object.  So annotations are common.